# Django não cria arquivo admin.py em novo app

Tags: django, python-2.7

Estou seguindo umas vídeo aulas sobre Django para fazer umas alteração em um projeto iniciado a algum tempo por outra pessoa. Porém, ao iniciar um novo **app** neste projeto com o comando

```
django-admin start app mad
```

são criados os arquivos: `__init__.py`, `models.py`, `testes.py` e `views.py`, mas não o `admin.py`.

Minha versão do Django é 1.3.4 e Python 2.7

O que fazer neste caso? Posso criar o arquivo manualmente, ou é possível haja algo errado nas configurações?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wilker,

Provavelmente seja a versão do django que você está utilizando, eu estou com a versão 1.10 e o arquivo admin.py é criado.

Verifique também no arquivo **settings.py** em **INSTALLED_APPS** se existe o valor **'django.contrib.admin'**.

De qualquer maneira você pode criar o arquivo admin.py manualmente, com o conteúdo inicial conforme abaixo:

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

Comment: Perfeito, como pude ver [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14883236/6036182) parece que é criado por padrão a partir da versão 1.6. 

Criei o arquivo manualmente e adicionei a linha que vc disse e funcionou perfeitamente.

Se quiser adicionar esta info a sua resposta para ficar mais completa para o futuro.